# My 9 slice sprite doesn't act properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, slice

I'm trying to use a 9 slice sprite in unity so that when the image is resized only the center and the sides are scaled, and the corners stay the same anytime. 
So I sliced my sprite, set the container (image) type to Sliced.
However when I run my code, the entire sprite suddenly show up in the center slice (so is resized in a weird way) leaving the sides and corners transparent. 
What could I be missing ?

It should be the first case but when i run the second case happens :

[image]

[image]

here is how I sliced the sprite (sorry hard to see but its white corners over a transparent background) :

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the image in the sprite editor so we can see, how you sliced it (also showing inspector).

Comment: sure there you go

Comment: Is the image type of the button image set to `sliced` (`tiled` should work too I think)?

Comment: yes it is set to sliced

Comment: Hmm, I can't really tell what is wrong or test it right now.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with the code you mentioned? Can you post it here?

Comment: Did you press apply? Its a dumb thing but happened me many times :)

Comment: Aha lol yes I pressed apply, I dont have the code right now but I'll post it tomorrow